# Adding local .aar file into android Project

Tags: android, aar

I have create .aar file from another project and added to new project.I have seen Classes are there but method name has changed.If i trying to access any method i have add in that class, got no method by that name. Finally I have seen method are like this.

```
public static void a(Context var0) {
        if(var0 != null) {
            var0.startService(new Intent(var0, TrackLocationOfficial.class));
        }

}
```

method name has changed to a(), b(),c(). 
what to do?
is local .aar is working ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `.aar` was minified with proguard, this causes the methods to be renamed.

Answer (score 0):

In the gradle file of your module you have enabled proguard, just disable that by

minifyEnabled false

You have to do it in your different configurations as in build and release separately